# Accidentally committed during rebase, continued, then re-committed and pushed using --amend --reset-author when committing. Am I SOL?

Tags: git, github

I messed up in a way I have not seen a solution for resolving due to how I so brilliantly used **--amend --reset-author** when committing to keep everything on the same commit. Basically, I completed work on a branch, committed and pushed, and then:

1. checked out master and pulled
2. checked out my branch
3. git rebase master, had merge conflict, fixed it
4. git commit --amend --reset-author BEFORE completing the rebase (oops)
5. git push -f (fatal, you're not on a branch)
6. git rebase --continue
7. git commit --amend --reset-author
8. git push -f

After force pushing is when I realized that I completely botched the rebase and now when I diff it's including code that isn't mine as changes. Is there any way to fix this? I unfortunately do not have a commit history to work with so I think I might be SOL here.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks so much for the links. Wow yes I think git reflog might actually do the trick. I didn't see on github ANY history of this thing so I thought all hope was lost. git reflog shows a bunch of stuff

Comment: git reflog is the ultimate butt saver.

Comment: The reflog stuff is local, in your own Git repository; GitHub do not keep good reflogs.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It worked!! Wow. I was almost in tears haha. This is the coolest git trick I've ever learned. Thanks again for the links. I had looked at a couple and didn't have the confidence to try until you shared. Seriously saved my butt with this. I wish I could mark that as accepted for you.

Comment: @torek Yeah as I just learned! So good to know.